# Java.Jmeter. SSL unexpected server Message "server_hello"

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, jmeter

I try to use Jmeter with plugin "DI-fakfa meter" to load my kafka using SSL.

I got the following certificates from VAULT system:
-CA
-Issuing CA
-Private key
In PEM format.

For Jmeter i import it with keytool:
1.merged files Issuing CA and private key, import it with
keytool in JKS format next command:"keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file "name_file" -keystore privatekey.jks"

1. Add privatekey.jks as keystore in Jmeter
2. import file CA.pem in Jks and add it to truststore in Jmeter.

Start Jmeter with -Djavax.net.debug = SSL,handshake.

in console i got error:
"Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Unexpected handshake message: server hello".

In python code this certificates works normaly in pem format.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're able to successfully run the request in Python code you should be able to do this in JMeter, enable tracing of the [SSL handshake](https://www.websecurity.digicert.com/security-topics/how-does-ssl-handshake-work) for both Python and JMeter and compare the packets and especially the certificate chain - they need to be the same.

Also I don't know what "DI-fakfa meter" is, I recall using [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) for load testing the system where SSL-enabled Kafka was used as the transport chain between microservices without any issues.

The relevant setup would be something like:

[image]

More information:

- [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
- 
- [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter)

Comment: yeah? i tried peper-box too, but have the same error

Comment: Did your peper-box works on last Jmeter version? I havent ssl propreties in this plugin on last Jmete version

Comment: maybe you can tell me how you import pem certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You need libs kafka-clients 2.8.1, bouncycastle and java.

Something like this:

```
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider;

String private_key = "certs as string" //pem format
String certificate = "certs as string" //pem format
String issuing_ca = "certs as string" //pem format
String common = "mla-bla"
String kafka_topic = "LOAD.TESTING" //topic

Properties props = new Properties();
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_KEY_CONFIG, private_key);
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, "PEM");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, "PEM");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_CONFIG, certificate);
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CERTIFICATES_CONFIG, issuing_ca);

props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, common);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-supapupa-1:9093");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("${kafka_topic}", "${kkey}", "load_test_jmeter-" + "${rand}");

try{
    producer.send(record);
    producer.flush();
    producer.close()
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
     log.info("Exception =" + e);
}
```